# How to add xsl stylesheet node to XML produced by XmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, rest, xslt

I have an WCF REST service which returns objects serialized with XmlSerializer.
How can I add XSL stylesheet information (like the one below) to the output returned by the WCF service?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transforms/Customer.xsl"?>
<Customer>
    <Name>Foo</Name>
</Customer>
```

My current operationcontract:

```
[OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
[WebGet( UriTemplate = "{id}" )]
Customer GetById( string id );
```

What I would prefer to be able to do, in order to control the stylesheet reference:

```
[OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
[XslStylesheet( Href = "transforms/Customer.xsl" )]
[WebGet( UriTemplate = "{id}" )]
Customer GetById( string id );
```

Comment: Did you get this working? Care to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://shevaspace.blogspot.com/2009/01/include-xml-declaration-in-wcf-restful.html) decribes how to introduce a `[IncludeXmlDeclaration]` attribute.  You should be able to something similar for your XslStylesheet attribute.